# Migración docker

Tags: .net, docker

Tengo una aplicación que corre sobre .Net framework 1.1 en un Windows Server 2008. La idea es migrar la aplicación a Windows Server 2016. Tengo entendido que .Net framework 1.1 no funcionaría en versiones posteriores. Podría usar docker para está migración?

Comment: Es como una pregunta demasiado amplia... con una respuesta si o no.. lo intentaste, que problema tuviste?

Comment: Creo que la respuesta es sí.. siempre y cuando sea un windows-docker corriendo windows server 2008.